# Why `select` does not replace existing columns?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

[DOC](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#select) for `select` attribute:

> select indicates which columns should be selected from the storage

This works as expected:

```
$rs->search( undef, { select => [ 'me.id', 'me.user_id' ] } )
   ->search( undef, { select => [ 'me.role_id' ] } )

$rs->as_query; # SELECT "me"."role_id" FROM "users_roles" "me"
```

But this does not:

```
$rs->search( undef, { prefetch => [ 'User' ] } )
   ->search( undef, { select => [ 'User.name' ] } )

$rs->as_query; # SELECT "User"."name", "User"."id", "User"."email", "User"."name" FROM "users_roles" "me"  JOIN "users" "User" ON "User"."id" = "me"."user_id"
```

The [`prefetch`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#prefetch) implies `+columns` ( which is: `+select` and `+as` ).
I alter `select` in second `search` by requesting only one column: `name`

What did I miss?
Why I still get columns `name`, `id`, `email`, `name` instead of only one `name`?

Comment: Related [mailing list thread](http://lists.scsys.co.uk/pipermail/dbix-class/2010-February/008925.html).

Comment: @nwellnhof: Thank you for the link, but I, actually, not exclude. I say: "Select me only one column" but it selects me another columns too. That is redundantly.

Comment: The thread is still somewhat related. Anyway, `prefetch` simply works independently from `select`.

Comment: Have you tried `get_column` ? As in `$rs->get_column('name')`?

Comment: The `select` is for telling it what to select from the tables you're querying. But the `prefetch` is more of an addon that fetches related rows from other tables, so you'll have a single multi-join query instead of later doing multiple individual queries. You cannot ask it to only prefetch a few cols. I _think_ you can tell it to do get only th `User.name` if you build the join yourself with `join` instead of `prefetch`.

Comment: @bytepusher: How that should help?

Comment: @simbabque: >`prefetch` attribute is a shorthand for specifying a `join` spec, adding all columns from the joined related sources as `+columns` and setting `collapse` to a true value. Also from the DOC: `columns` replaces `+columns`. I tend to conside this as a bug. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

If I rewrite `prefetch` by join. This works fine:

```
$rs->search( undef, { 
    ,join => [ 'User' ]
    ,collaplse => 1
    ,'+columns' => [map
        { +{ "cds.$_" => "cds.$_" } }
        $c->db->source('Right')->related_source('User')->columns
    ]
})->search( undef, { select => [ 'User.name' ] } )

$rs->as_query; # SELECT "User"."name" FROM "users_roles" "me"  JOIN "users" "User" ON "User"."id" = "me"."user_id"
```

So it seems there is a bug with `prefetch`. Because `join`+`collapse`+`+columns` is not same as `prefetch`:

[DOC](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/DBIx-Class-0.082840/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSet.pm#prefetch)

> This attribute is a shorthand for specifying a "join" spec, adding all columns from the joined related sources as "+columns" and setting "collapse" to a true value.

Also docs states:

> For example, the following two queries are equivalent

As you can see `join` and `prefetch` are **not equivalent**